# Modifying quantity in stock by the amount of ordered quantity

Tags: c

I have a method called AddOrder() where the user creates an order. As the system asks the user to enter Product Name, the system gets the specific record from the products.dat file. The user is then asked the amount of product quantity and to confirm the order. As the order record is confirmed, I want the system to update the quanity in stock in the products.dat file y subtracting from it the amount of product quantity of that particular product. Unfortunately, the quanity in stock is remaining unchanged. This is my code.

```
void addOrder()
{
    FILE *pfp;
    order o1;
    product p;
    char ProductName[100];
    int found = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    int tmpStock = 0;
    double pPrice = 0.0;
    int choice2 = 0;

    ofp=fopen("orders.dat","ab");
    pfp=fopen("products.dat", "rb");



    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Adding an Order\n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter CustomerID: \n");
        scanf("%s",&o1.CustomerID);
    }while(!findCustomer(o1.CustomerID));


    printf("Enter Product Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", ProductName);

    while(1)
    {
    fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pfp);

    if(feof(pfp))
    {
    break;
    }
    if(strcmp(ProductName,p.ProductName)==0)
    {
        found = 1;
        tmpStock = p.QuantityInStock;
        pPrice = p.price;

    }
    }
    if(found == 0)
    {
        printf("The Product was not found!\n");
        OrdersSubMenu();
    }

    printf("Enter Product Quantities: \n");
    scanf("%d", &o1.ProductQuantities);

    if(o1.ProductQuantities > tmpStock)
    {
        printf("You have axeceeded available stock! Available Stock: %d\n", tmpStock);
        printf("Do you want to enter product quantity again(press 1)\n");
        printf("or order a different product(press 2)?\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
             printf("Enter Product Quantities: \n");
             scanf("%d", &o1.ProductQuantities);
        }
        else
        if(choice == 2)
        {
            OrdersSubMenu();
        }
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Product Quantity is available\n");
    }

    o1.TotalOrderPrice = o1.ProductQuantities * pPrice;
    printf("Total Order Price: %.2f\n", o1.TotalOrderPrice);

    printf("Do you want to confirm order? If yes press 1, if no press 2: \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice2);

    if(choice2 == 1)
    {
        fwrite(&o1,sizeof(o1),1,ofp);


    }
    else
        if(choice2 == 2)
    {
        OrdersSubMenu();
    }


    printf("Order record was added to the system!\n");

    tmpStock = tmpStock-o1.ProductQuantities;
    p.QuantityInStock =tmpStock;


    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(pfp);
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I already used printf to check the value of tmpStock after applying the subtraction. As the program reached the statement, it stopped working, saying: products.exe has stopped working. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Run the program under a debugger. When the program stops working, the debugger will tell you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want the system to update the quanity in stock in the products.dat file*

But you are only opening products.dat for read access `pfp=fopen("products.dat", "rb");`.

Your `fwrite` statement is to `ofp`, which is opened to a different file: `ofp=fopen("orders.dat","ab");`

The variable `ofp` is not declared, so at least one line of your code is missing, otherwise it would not compile.  Update:  for some reason `ofp` it has been made global, but why?  Nevertheless that should not affect the functionality (assuming a single thread).

Edit:  to write and write to a file, open it with mode "r+b".  You need to find the product whose stock you wish to update, and then *move the current file position backwards*;

```
fseek(pfp, -sizeof(product), SEEK_CUR);
```

then `fwrite` the new product record.  Note the - sign on the sizeof: we are moving the current file position to the start of the record we just read.

Comment: ofp is declared as static FILE *ofp; at the beginning before the addOrder method. I think that's why the quantity in stock is not changing. But how should I read and write a file at the same time in the same method?

Comment: I changed the mode to r+b and added fseek and fwrite, but now the system can't find the product.

Comment: Check the file format using somthing like od(1).